# Plugin.MediaManager.Forms is not working in xamarin uwp

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, plugin.mediamanager.forms

[Reference](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/777)

I am using `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms` for playing audio. It is working fine in android and ios. But in windows, the app is breaking with `System.NotImplementedException.`.

[image]

**Version Details:**

*Plugin.MediaManager.Forms: 1.0.7*

*Xamarin Forms: 4.8.0.1821*

*Visual Studio: 16.8.3*

*Windows Target version: Windows 10 version 1903(10.0; Build 18362)*

*Windows Min Version: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; Build 16299)*

*Also, I have added the "Background Media Playback", "Internet", "Music Library" and "Videos Library" in the Package.appxmanifest under capabilities.*

What else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Plugin.MediaManager.Forms is not working in xamarin uwp

It looks a bug for `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms`, Please try to reduce Plugin.MediaManager.Forms version to **0.9.6**. And call `CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();` in UWP client project like the following. It will work.

```
 if (rootFrame == null)
 {
     // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
     rootFrame = new Frame();

     rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

     Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
     CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
     ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(600, 900); 
     ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
     
     if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
     {
         //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
     }

     // Place the frame in the current Window
     Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
 }
```

Comment: Version reducing is only for windows or for all the projects?

Comment: The better is for all projects.

Answer (score 1):

I already saw your issue on github and now saw this stack question.
I fixed this problem in my [Pull Request](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/pull/779). When the PR gets merged you can update to the newest version. You have to use **UWP 10.0.18362.0(Version 1903)** min by the way.

The Target Version was downgraded from uap 10.0.18362.0(Version 1903) to 10.0.17763(Version 1809) from version *0.9.7* to *0.9.9*. For now, you have to use **v. 0.9.7**.